# how can i install bootstrap on nuxtjs

Tags: bootstrap-4, nuxtjs

I want to use Bootstrap in nuxt.js, how can I do this without using CDN? I want to use bootstrap files in the nuxt.config.js, but I can't, also I want to use jquery files and popper.js
I tried to include those files on head array on the `nuxt.config.js` but it's doesn't work, and also I tried to include `bootstrap.min.css` on CSS array and fortunately it worked, but js property of bootstrap like Dropdown, Collapses and stuff like that didn't work, I know the reason why those properties don't work, its because Jquery and popper js didn't include, but really how can i include them?
please help me

Comment: please add some code, so its easier to find possible mistakes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use bootsrap-vue or if you want to use pure bootstrap you can add CDN or download files add them manually:

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        src: '/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js'
      },
      {
        src: '/popper.min.js'
      },
      {
        src: '/bootstrap.min.js'
      }
    ],
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/bootstrap.min.css'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I knew how to use of CDN, but I don't want use of it for some reasons, I want  use manual files, and I include bootstrap.min.css in CSS array on nuxt.config.js its work, but I don't know how can I include js files , which needs for working  pure bootstrap like jquery and popper.js, which usually used for DropDown and Copllapse

Comment: @MohammadAli Just add them in `static` folder and change src as my edit in answer.

Comment: Here is how to accept answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 3):

here is a way I found to install bootstrap in Nuxt Js
firstly, you need to install the sass and sass loader packages by using

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader@10 fibers
```

Secondly, you install [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/) using npm

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

thirdly, go into your assets folder create a folder named scss, and inside the scss folder create an app.scss or any name you wish
fourthly, you import bootstrap from your node modules by using the @import that is

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

fifthly, you go to the nuxt.config.js and you add your scss file you created by using,

```
{ src: '~/assets/scss/app.scss', lang: 'scss' },
```

here is the link for a project I did from github [bootstrap-nuxt](https://github.com/WendahNyiawung/bootstrap-nuxt)

Answer (score -1):

Try this steps:

1. Install Bootstrap using this command `npm install bootstrap-vue`
2. Add this line to your nuxt.config.js

   `module.exports = { modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt'] }`

I hope I understood your question right. For more information, you can check Getting Started part of the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't want using of bootstrap-vue because its doesn't support of RTL, and it's hard to change config for RTL support